# How to add an array to end of existing array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
$insert_query = array(
            array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'),
            array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
);
```

after other portion of code, I want to append a new array at the end of `$insert_query` array

Which is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

I found this working way: using `array_push`

```
$insert_query = array(
            array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'),
            array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
);

...
#OTHER CODE
...

array_push($insert_query, array('uno', 'due', 'tre', 'quattro', 'cinque'));
```

and if I have a `var_dump($insert_query)`, all seems working well

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "one"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "two"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "three"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "four"
    [4]=>
    string(4) "five"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "uno"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "due"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "tre"
    [3]=>
    string(7) "quattro"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "cinque"
  }
}
```

Comment: As you've found `array_push` will do it. You can also append using the following syntax: `$insert_query[] = array('uno', 'due', 'tre', 'quattro', 'cinque');`